# JqGrid custom button doesn't show

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I want to add a custom button which allows showing/hiding columns in the jqGrid.

This used to work but then I updated to the following (as suggested by Oleg)

- [Link1](https://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/css/ui.jqgrid.css)
- [Link2](https://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js)
- [Link3](https://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js)

Now the button does not even appear anymore.

```
var grid = $('#table');
            $('#table').jqGrid({
                datatype: 'jsonstring',
                editurl: 'ajax/modify',
                mtype: 'POST',
                loadonce: false,
                datastr: jobs,
                height: 600,
                autowidth: true,
                forceFit: true,
                gridview: true,
                viewrecords: true,
                multiselect: true,
                sortable: false,
                toppager: true,
                treeGrid: true,
                treeGridModel: 'adjacency',
                treedatatype: 'POST',
                ExpandColumn: 'jobType',
                ExpandColClick: true,
                colNames: [
                    "Id ",
                    "Job Type"
                ],
                colModel: [{
                    name: 'id',
                    index: 'id',
                    editable: true,
                    edittype: 'text',
                    key: true
                }, {
                    name: 'jobType',
                    index: 'jobType',
                    editable: true,
                    edittype: 'text'
                }],
                jsonReader: {
                    repeatitems: false,
                    root: function(obj) {
                        return obj;
                    },
                    page: function() {
                        return 1;
                    },
                    total: function() {
                        return 1;
                    },
                    records: function(obj) {
                        return obj.length;
                    }
                });

grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#table_toppager', {
                edit: true,
                add: true,
                refresh: false,
                //view: true,
                del: false,
                search: false,
                alertcap: 'Alert',
                alerttext: 'Please select a row to edit.'
            }, { //options for EDITting an existing record
                topinfo: 'Edit the database entries for the selected row. ',
                editCaption: "Edit",
                bSubmit: "Submit",
                bCancel: "Close",
                bClose: "Close",
                saveData: "Do you want to save the changes? ",
                bYes: "Save",
                bNo: "Cancel",
                bExit: "Don't Save",
                viewPagerButtons: false,
                savekey: [true, 13],
                width: 500,
                recreateForm: true}).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', "#table_toppager_left", {
                caption: "Show/Hide Columns",
                buttonicon: "ui-icon-newwin",
                onClickButton: function() {
                    grid.jqGrid('columnChooser', {
                        done: function(perm) {
                            if (!perm) {
                                return false;
                            }
                            this.jqGrid('remapColumns', perm, true);
                        }
                    });
                },
                //position: "last",
                title: "Columns",
                cursor: "pointer"
            });
```

Comment: I see that you declared the column having `key: true` as editable (`editable: true`). Moreover you use `id` name for the column. Both could have side effects. In general there are 5 column name which are reserved: `"cb"`, `"nm"`, `"subgrid"`, `"_id_"` and `"id"`. One can in general allow to use only one from the 5 reserved names: `"id"`, but one have to add `localReader: { id: "myKey" }` and `jsonReader: { id: "myKey" }`. I'd recommend you to avoid the usage of `"id"` name for the column.

Comment: I thought I needed the id column for the treegrid as it is being referred to for the 'parent' ? I don't actually need to show it in my grid.

Comment: You should add only the columns which you need to **show** the user. Other properties which need jqGrid will be read automatically. In any way you should **don't make `id` column editable**. I posted you the demo an the end on my answer. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/user3710760_.htm) without `id` column work too. To add child node you need first select the node which you want make its parent.

Comment: Thanks, I removed it now and it works too. So do you mean that I can remove all columns from the colModel if they are supposed to be `hidden: true`, even if I need in my data set I can still refer to them?

Comment: You should exactly define what you want and what other parameters you use. For example in case of `datatype: "local"` all data will be saved automatically. In more common case you will need to use `additionalProperties` with array of properties which you want to read and save in local data. TreeGrid for example append automatically `additionalProperties` with all TreeGrid specific properties. See [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/additionalProperties-option-makes-unneeded-hidden-columns-in-local-scenario).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the bug report. I made some changes in the code because of there the reading of some specific parts of `iconSet` configurations (only the "common" part) was broken. I have fixed the code. You need to reload the sources from the github or retry with the current source from `https://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/...` URLs.

Because you use free jqGrid I would recommend you additionally to use the new style of the options. See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/New-style-of-usage-options-of-internal-methods) for details. It allows to specify many default options of other methods like the option of `navGrid`. It reduces the code to the about following

```
$("#table").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    //editurl: "ajax/modify",
    datastr: jobs,
    height: 600,
    autowidth: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    multiselect: true,
    toppager: true,
    treeGrid: true,
    iconSet: "fontAwesome",
    sortable: true,
    treeGridModel: "adjacency",
    treedatatype: "POST",
    ExpandColumn: "jobType",
    ExpandColClick: true,
    colNames: [ "Id", "Job Type" ],
    colModel: [
        { name: "id", key: true },
        { name: "jobType", editable: true }
    ],
    navOptions: {
        refresh: false,
        del: false,
        search: false,
        alertcap: "Alert",
        alerttext: "Please select a row to edit."
    },
    formEditing: {
        topinfo: "Edit the database entries for the selected row. ",
        editCaption: "Edit",
        bSubmit: "Submit",
        bCancel: "Close",
        bClose: "Close",
        saveData: "Do you want to save the changes? ",
        bYes: "Save",
        bNo: "Cancel",
        bExit: "Don't Save",
        viewPagerButtons: false,
        savekey: [true, 13],
        width: 500
        //recreateForm: true - it's needed in free jqGrid
        //                     only to reset dialog position
    }
}).jqGrid("navGrid")
.jqGrid("showHideColumnMenu")
.jqGrid("navButtonAdd", {
        caption: "Show/Hide Columns",
        //buttonicon: "ui-icon ui-icon-newwin",
        onClickButton: function () {
            $(this).jqGrid("columnChooser");
        },
        title: "Columns",
        cursor: "pointer"
    });
```

I recommend you to include additionally `iconSet: "fontAwesome"` option and `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`. It makes many icons scalable. If you need still combine Font Awesome icons (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Using-Font-Awesome-in-free-jqGrid-4.8) and [here](http://fontawesome.io/icons/)) with jQuery UI icons you will need just add the icons like `"ui-icon ui-icon-newwin"` instead of `"ui-icon-newwin"` (additional `"ui-icon"` class).

One more tip to you: you can include `<script src="https://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/plugins/jquery.jqgrid.showhidecolumnmenu.js"></script>` which required `jquery-ui.min.js` or `jquery-ui.js` additionally. It provides `showHideColumnMenu` method which you can call just without any parameters (`$('#table').jqGrid('showHideColumnMenu');`). It uses jQuery UI Menu to create **context menu in column headers** of the grid for hiding/showing columns of the grid. If you add `sortable: true` option the one will be able to reorder the columns by drag&drop of the column headers and hide/show by right mouse click (by context menu).

See the demo with your code [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/user3710760.htm).